# How to parse CURRENT_DATETIME() at ("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") in BigQuery

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I am trying to parse using the `format_date("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", CURRENT_DATETIME()) as date_mod` but it gives me error:

> No matching signature for function FORMAT_DATE for argument types: STRING, DATETIME. Supported signature: FORMAT_DATE(STRING, DATE) at [2:9]

I used the FORMAT_DATETIME, without result.

Help pls. 
Thx!

Comment: what you mean by "I used the FORMAT_DATETIME, without result."? `FORMAT_DATETIME` is what to be used here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the error message that you are getting, [`FORMAT_DATE()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date) is there to format values of the `DATE` datatype.

If you have a `DATETIME` (which `CURRENT_DATETIME()` returns), then you want [`FORMAT_DATETIME()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#format_datetime):

```
format_datetime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", CURRENT_DATETIME())
```